# Xcode 4.2: What is the most effective method switching views?

Tags: xcode, view, switching, xcode4.2

I was thinking of games in particular, where there may be alot of views that need to be switched in and out. Could someone supply some sample xcode 4.2 code? Many tutorials have old xcode versions which have different initial code.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Most efficient method I would say is usin the story board feature. Set up a new view controller inside the main storyboard file and then control drag from which red button on one view to the next one. Very easy and no code required.  Email me if you had any problems dai.evans94@live.co.uk